# Select part of a text that exists already in an above cell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2003, autocomplete

How do I get Excel to partially auto-complete a word using another that already exist in the same worksheet?

Let's say I have the word "Microsoft" in a cell and in the cell below I want to type the word "Microhard".

When I start typing Microhard, the word Microsoft appears shaded in black.

How can I select the "Micro" part alone from Microsoft and continue to fill out the rest with "hard" without it trying to fill out as Microsoft?

Comment: Hopefully the edit makes the question clearer and is also what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `F2` to enter the cell, start typing with `'m'`. This will bring up the highlighted text. Once it appears, use the arrow keys to skip to the end of the text. Use the Shift + right arrow key repeatedly to select 'soft', then overwrite it with 'hard'.

It's a pity that Excel doesn't support accepting the highligted text without exiting the cell.

Comment: How to use the arrow keys to get past micro.? Pressing the arrow keys takes me to the end of the text.!!!

Comment: Right. Selected text gets skipped when using the arrow keys and there's no way to unselect the text without exiting the cell. I'll adjust the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"esc" and "undo" are your friends (especially when Microsoft products try to auto-correct non-mistakes for you).  Also, the formula bar above the spreadsheet allows you to edit the content of any cell if it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you just start typing into a cell, you can not change the selection or the cursor position with the arrow keys. Using the arrow keys in that case changes the cell.

Now, if you start editing the cell using <kbd>F2</kbd>, you can use the arrow keys to change the cursor position.

So in your case, follow these steps:

- Press <kbd>F2</kbd> on the empty cell underneath 'Microsoft'.
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> (now 'Microsoft' should be in the cell with 'icrosoft' selected (shaded in black)).
- Press <kbd>-></kbd> (now your cursor should be at the end of 'Microsoft').
- Press <kbd>backspace</kbd> 4 times to erase 'soft' (now there is should be only 'Micro' in the cell).
- Type 'hard' (Now the cell should contain 'Microhard').

Comment: But i wanted to select text 'Micro' alone. consider if the word has 20 characters and the first 10 characters  repeats in the second word too. So in this case i need to delete 10 characters right.? Rather if there is something to select it would be easier.!!

Comment: @pragadheesh: I don't understand what's the problem. You could also select the part to remove using [shift-left arrow] in stead of backspace. I don't think there's a faster way to do what you want. After all, you only have to do this once, the next time you type 'micros' you automatically have 'Microsoft' selected and if you type 'microh' you automatically have 'Microhard' selected. You could also copy 'Micro' to the clipboard, and the do ctrl-v and type 'hard' or 'soft'. I think you're trying to optimize the wrong things.